# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Data> to MyCollection

Tags: java, generics

I've read similar questions here but I'm still a little confused.

```
 MyCollection extends ArrayList<MyClass>

 MyClass implements Data
```

yet this gives me the "cannot convert from ArrayList to MyCollection"

```
 MyCollection mycollection = somehandler.getCollection();
```

where getCollection looks like this

```
 public ArrayList<Data> getCollection()
```

So my assumptions are obviously wrong. How can I make this work like I would like it to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList` does not extend `MyCollection`. It's the other way round.

There are several ways to fix this problem, depending on the functional requirement:

1. You need to provide a `MyCollection` constructor which can take another `Collection`.
2. If the actual type is `MyCollection`, then you need to cast `ArrayList` to `MyCollection`.
3. If the actual type is `MyCollection`, then you need to change return type to `MyCollection`.

That said, what makes `MyCollection` so different that it apparently doesn't adhere the `List`'s contract and you hence need to cast/convert it? This shouldn't happen, I would rethink the design/approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign to subtype from super type, but you can implement a Copy Constructor, then you could do the same thing like this:

```
MyCollection myCollection = new MyCollection(somehandler.getCollection());
```

Edit: the type of the parameter to the constructor could be for example List.

Answer (score 1):

Well, imagine you have

```
class SecondCollection extends ArrayList<MyClass>
```

then what would `ArrayList<MyClass>` be cast to?

You need to either expect `ArrayList` or return `MyCollection`, or copy the contents of the `ArrayList` to a new instance of `MyCollection`, or explicitly cast to `MyCollection`. I don't recommend the last option.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to cast the result

`MyCollection mycollection = (MyCollection) somehandler.getCollection();`

edit : or change the return type of `getCollection()` to a `MyCollection`

Comment: That will only work if `getCollection` actually returns an object of type `MyCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out page 4 of [the generics tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Data>` cannot be cast to `MyCollection` or even to `ArrayList<MyClass>`.  See [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/juglugano/browse_thread/thread/c11531309ed37646) for a good explanation.